# Increasing textbox width from ajax response Value not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am trying to implement a progress bar , where i am getting increasing value from 0 to <100 from a ajax request, and adding "px" to it , Data is coming alright but not applying to width .

```
enter code here
  <input type="text" id="value" style="border:none;"/>
  <input type="text" id="progress" style="width:0px;background-color: red;"/>

    function fetchStatus()
    {
          xmlup=new XMLHttpRequest();   
          xmlup.onreadystatechange=function(){
              if(xmlup.readyState === 4 && xmlup.status === 200)    
                 {                         
                 document.getElementById("value").value=xmlup.responseText;//Working
                 document.getElementById("progress").style.width=xmlup.responseText+"px";
                //Not Working

                 }
                else
                 {
                 }
              };
                     xmlup.open("GET","ProgressStatus",true);       
                     xmlup.send();           
    }
```

Comment: And this fetchStatus() function is being called from setInterval() with a 1 sec gap

Comment: Your script looks correct. Try to debug it, add alert(xmlup.responseText); or console log it and check are you getting response.

Comment: Looks good. I checked it with static values and works well for me. Follow what @Ranjana said and debug it. 
JsFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/chechs/hac3k07m/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/chechs/hac3k07m/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your script is correct.

I'd say that the style `width` is been set correctly but there might be another CSS property (or class) that is prevent the width to be displayed correctly.